# How to use the Webform Serial in a Webform Rule?

Tags: rules, webforms

Is there a way to use the [Webform Serial](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_serial) (not the SID) be used in a webform rule?

I've tried the following with no success:

```
[data:serial]
[webform:serial]
[node:serial]
```

I do have [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) & [Webform Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_tokens) installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [comment #2 in issue #2572067](https://www.drupal.org/node/2572067#comment-10353611), which states this:

> The correct token for that is `[submission:serial]`, but some module is going to have to make that token available to the rules module. Webform itself doesn't do that. I haven't tried it, but the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) modules would be the place to start.
>
> The serial number is a relatively new feature, but I would have though it would work without an update to the Webform Rules module. If not, you might file an issue in that module's queue.